# Checking Silverlight Migration to Moonlight

Tags: silverlight, migration, moonlight

We're in the process of creating a Silverlight project and wondered how we could validate/test if it would run on Moonlight. From regular .Net to Mono there is the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) which generates a report on which methods are missing in Mono to provide full support.

Are there any similar tools from Silverlight to Moonlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there aren't any and event wouldn't be by my opinion.

The situation with moonlight is little bit more complicated.
With mono you're checking just clr methods towards standard. That's pretty easy.

Moonlight 1.0 is only stable version and should be 100% compatible with Silverlight, XAML is covered, but there are of course some bugs, the only comparision is on this page: http://go-mono.com/moonlight/MoonlightStatus.aspx.

Moonlight 2.0 is in beta state, there is clr part that can be checked with moma towards the mono version it's based on, cause the binaries are only stripped by mono linker. The API will be quite near 100% if not fully compleated. The rest is same like with Moonlight 1.0.
The status page is here: http://go-mono.com/moonlight/MoonlightStatus.aspx?v=2

Comment: I guess this is the best answer at this time

Answer (score 0):

Like Yakeen said, 2.0 is in beta. The best way to test is going to be installing moonlight on a test box and manually testing your site.

If it were me, I'd create a Virtual Machine with some flavor of Linux+Firefox and install the beta from [their download site](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight-beta/)